# VSCode Extension Dev: How do I know if vscode is connected to a remote or devcontainer?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vscode-remote, vscode-devcontainer

Is there a reliable way my extension can identify if the current vscode window is connected to a remote or devcontainer?  My extension helps configure our dev environments and I need to behave differently in those cases.  Thanks.

I've tried to find a vscode api that will tell me the remote status but cant find anything.

Comment: what is the difference in the URI scheme of local and remote workspace